# WCF Service with favicon?

Tags: wcf, favicon

Using a console app to serve a REST WCF service. Showing the WSDL in the browser is usually done in demonstrations. It would be cool to take the favicon.ico and have that appear instead of the IE logo, but there is no real "home directory". Is it possible to show the Favorites Icon when doing a web service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. REST services don't use WSDL - WSDL is a SOAP construct
2. The WSDL engine in WCF takes over the processing of GET requests to the metadata address and therefore you cannot engineer a response to favicon.ico (just tried to put a REST endpoint to do this side by side with the metadata and it doesn't get invoked)

The only thing you could do would be to generate the WSDL yourself and serve it from a REST endpoint which also had code to process favicon.ico (which seems like a lot of work to show an icon on a WSDL page - especially when WSDL isn't really designed for human consumption)

Comment: That is a lot of work for an icon. Just looking for cosmetics. The WCF service in question is consumed by Java clients (we go through pains to make it palatable to Axis 1.4) and humans do look at the WSDL quite a bit, so we already weave comments into the WSDL, so an icon would be something nice but definitely not worth the extra work. Thanks!